# How to prevent ngDialog scrolling up and down

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ngDialog 0.5.8 and angular 1.5.3.
I have created dialog:

```
ngDialog.open({
            template: 'myTemplate',
        });
```

And my page is scrolling down during opening a dialog, and scrolling up when I'm closing a dialog.

Is anybody here know how to configure ngDialog to not scrolling site during opening and closing?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found answer

Add css:

```
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And in js:

```
var bodyReference = angular.element( $document[0].body );

bodyReference.addClass('overflow-hidden');

var promise = ngDialog.open({
    template: 'myTemplate',
});

promise.closePromise.then(function (data) {
           //actions...
           bodyReference.removeClass('overflow-hidden');
        });
```